# gotoScene error using widget.newButton()

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I'm making a game app in Corona SDK and I'm getting an error when I click my start button in my interface that is trying to load up my first scene.

Here are my codes:

main.lua

```
`local storyboard = require "storyboard"
storyboard.gotoScene("menu")`
```

menu.lua

```
`local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local widget = require( "widget" )`

`local background = display.newImage("Legend of Kael.jpg", true) 
background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
background.y = display.contentHeight / 2`

`local roundedRect = display.newRoundedRect( 10, 50, 300, 40, 8 )
roundedRect.anchorX, roundedRect.anchorY = 0.0, 0.0     
roundedRect:setFillColor( 0/255, 0/255, 0/255, 170/255 )`

`local function handleButtonEvent( event )
if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
storyboard.gotoScene( "scene1", "crossFade", 400)
end
end`

`local button = widget.newButton
{
defaultFile = "buttonBlue.png",
overFile = "buttonBlueOver.png",
label = "Start Game",
emboss = true,
onEvent = handleButtonEvent,
}`

`button.x = 240; button.y = 200`

`function scene:createScene( event )
local group = self.view
end`

`function scene:enterScene( event )
storyboard.purgeScene("main")
local group = self.view
end`

`function scene:exitScene( event )
local group = self.view
storyboard.removeScene("main")
end`

`scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )`

`return scene`
```

scene1.lua

```
`local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()`

`local storyboard = require ("storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()`

`function scene:createScene(event)`

`local background = display.newImage("forest1.jpg" ,display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight)
background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
background.y = display.contentHeight / 2`

`local ground = display.newImage("ground.png")
ground:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
ground.x, ground.y = 0,420`

`local groundShape = {-420, -20, 420, -20, 420, 20, -420, 20}
physics.addBody(ground, "static", {friction = 1.0, density = 1.0, bounce = 0, shape = groundShape})`

`local char = display.newImage("char.png")
char.x = 70
char.y = 230`

`physics.addBody(char, {friction = 1.0, density = 1.0, bounce = 0.3, radius = 35})
char.isFixedRotation = true`

`local function onScreenTouch(event)
if event.phase == "began" then
char:applyForce(100, -500, char.x, char.y)
end`

`return true
end`

`end`

`Runtime:addEventListener("touch", onScreenTouch)`

`scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)`

`return scene`
```

The error that I'm getting is this:

```
`assertion failed!
stack traceback:`

`[C]: in function 'error'
?: in function 'gotoScene'
menu.lua:17:in function '_onEvent'
?: in function '?'
?: in function <?:424>
?: in function <?:218>`
```

I hope that you can find a solution in this problem. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Composer](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/) because ***"Not only is Composer easier to use, but it will also allow us to build better and more interesting things in the future."***

Regarding your error this is most likely due to storyboard trying to call a function that is not actually available. My best suggestion is that you read about composer and carefully follow the tutorial all the way through. Since storyboard is no longer being supported and composer is a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you are never adding anything to the storyboard's view group (i.e local group = self.view).  Normally your background and button would be inside the storyboard's createScene() function.  Once you create those objects you would insert each of them into the scene's view...

```
 group:insert( background )
```

for instance.  Because your scene's view is empty, it's probably throwing that error.

Rob